# How to count rows in table with condition WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a query that to count rows from table `question_category`:

```
SELECT
          idSpecialization,
          thematicspecialization.SpecializationName AS SpecializationName,
          SubscrubeToUsersIdNote,
          COUNT(question_categoryId) AS CNT,
          COUNT(idSubscrubeToUsers) AS SUBS
          FROM thematicspecialization
          LEFT JOIN question_category ON question_category.question_categoryIdCategory = thematicspecialization.idSpecialization
          LEFT JOIN question a ON a.idQuestion = question_category.question_categoryIdQuestion
          LEFT JOIN subscrubetousers ON (subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = idSpecialization AND subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = 4 AND SubscrubeToUsersStatus = 1)

WHERE a.country = 1
GROUP BY idSpecialization
```

Need display the category names of `thematicspecialization` with the condition WHERE `a.country = 1` for joining tables `question a ON a.idQuestion = question_category.question_categoryIdQuestion`

In my case - the categories are not displayed.

Comment: What do you mean "categories are not displayed"? If you query for the count of categories, the categories themselves are not supposed to be displayed; the "group by" query returns their count, without showing the individual categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a ocmment.

This is your query, fixed up a bit to use table aliases so it is easier to read:

```
SELECT ts.idSpecialization, ts.SpecializationName, sts.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote,
       COUNT(question_categoryId) AS CNT,
       COUNT(idSubscrubeToUsers) AS SUBS
FROM thematicspecialization ts LEFT JOIn
     question_category qc
     ON qc.question_categoryIdCategory = ts.idSpecialization LEFT JOIN
     question q
     ON q.idQuestion = qc.question_categoryIdQuestion LEFT JOIN
     subscrubetousers sts
     ON (sts.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = ts.idSpecialization AND
         sts.SubscrubeToUsersType = 4 AND
         sts.SubscrubeToUsersStatus = 1)
WHERE q.country = 1
GROUP BY idSpecialization;
```

Here are things that I notice:

1. The join between `ts` and `qc` is on `IdCategory` and `idSpecialization`.  That seems like a strange combination of names.
2. The join between  `sts` and `ts` is partly on `SubscrubeToUsersIdNote` and `idSpecialization`.  That seems like a strange combination of names.
3. The `where` condition is turning some `left join`s into inner joins -- calling into question why you want `left join` anyway.
4. The two `count` columns are going to return very similar numbers, because they are counting non-NULL values on `join` keys`.
5. Your question is about "categories" and their "names".  However, based on your query, it is entirely unclear what fields these refer to.

Based on this query, I have no idea what you are really trying to do.  You should probably write another question, with sample data and desired output to express what you are trying to do.  This question already has two answers.  Clarifying it so it would be understood would (probably) invalidate the answers, which is impolite.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear.
But I guess. You have a join with condition like

```
subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = idSpecialization AND subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = 4 AND SubscrubeToUsersStatus = 1be this
```

May be this condition conflict `thematicspecialization` field